# How to fix "qemu-system-mipsel: The following two regions overlap (in the memory address space)"?

Tags: qemu, overlapping

I would like to run a Linux root filesystem for MIPSEL on qemu-system-mipsel.
The root filesystem was extracted from the firmware using "firmware-analysis-toolkit" (firmadyne).

However, After I build a root filesystem as required I encountered an error when I run

The script for run qemu is:

```
qemu-system-mipsel -M malta -kernel vmlinuz.elf \
  -drive if=ide,format=raw,file=squashfs-factory.raw \
  -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0 nandsim.parts=64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64 \ 
           rdinit=/firmadyne/preInit.sh rw debug ignore_loglevel print-fatal-signals=1 user_debug=31 firmadyn \
  -nographic
```

If i use the vmlinux.elf provided by firmadyne toolkit (kernel 2.6.39.4+) everything works.

If i want to use a vmlinux.elf (kernel 5.4) provided by openwrt-imagebuilder (or compiled by me) i encountered an error this error:

```
The following two regions overlap (in the memory address space):
vmlinux-5.4.111.mipsel ELF program header segment 0 (addresses 0x0000000000001000 - 0x000000000084b910)
prom (addresses 0x0000000000002000 - 0x0000000000003040)
```

I've tried everything. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

QEMU is complaining that the ELF file you've asked it to load is overlapping with the blob of 'prom' data that contains data to pass to the kernel such as memory size and the kernel command line. That PROM data always starts at address 0x2000. You need to build your kernel so that it doesn't try to put anything at that address.